# How to increment a column values by 1 while creating factory in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5.6

I want to generate 1000 users and then generate another 1000 record for the NewUser table which is working properly but the registration_no field is breaking the unique key constraint.

So i guess its always storing value 1 in registration field.

```
        $i = 1;

        factory(App\User::class, 1000)->states('newuser')->create()
        ->each(function ($u) use($i)
        {

            $u->newuser()->save(factory(App\NewUser::class)->make([
                'registration_no' => $i,
            ]));

            $i++;

        })
```

So how do I actually increment the field by 1 everytime new user is created ?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want a registration_no that increments by 1?  Wouldn't this be a duplicate field when you already have an auto-increment id?

Comment: well this is just an example. In real application the scenario is different. The main part is how do I generate 1000 users with one of the field incrementing by 1 everytime.

Comment: I would expect your code to work, although, I'd probably just use $i++ in the make() instead of a $i++ afterwards.  I'm not sure I understand the NewUser relationship you have there but $i should be incrementing.

Comment: Perhaps you already have a few records in your newuser table?

Comment: It gives error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: The call back in the `each()` method has a second parameter `$key` which should be the index of the current looped item and it should work for you.

Comment: I tried using $key but it does not work. It says undefined variable key

Answer (score 1):

to increase $i value for each new user you must use `use(&$i)` to pass reference instead of `use($i)` which supply 1 to closure on every run